# Possible error in Wood's report on polylogarithms

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

I'm studying the article by Wood, D.C. "The Computation of Polylogarithms. Technical Report 15-92*" [PS](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/pubs/1992/110) (it is remarkably poorly translated from latex to ps). It  is listed in the literature section on wiki page on [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

In particular, in section $11$ the author studies

$$ -Li_p(-e^w) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{t-w}+1}\mathrm dt$$

and then in order to obtain the asymptotics, splits the integral in $w$ (I took the case where $w\in\mathbb R$). Somehow the result is

$$\displaystyle-Li_p(-e^w) = \frac{w^p}{\Gamma(p+1)} + \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^{w}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{w-t}+1}\mathrm dt + \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_w^{\infty}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{t-w}+1}\mathrm dt,$$

yet when I do the same calculations, I get

$$-\Gamma(p)Li_p(-e^w) = \int_0^{w}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{t-w}+1}\mathrm dt+  \int_w^{\infty}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{t-w}+1}\mathrm dt$$
$$= \int_0^{w}\frac{e^{w-t}t^{p-1}}{e^{w-t}+1}\mathrm dt+  \int_w^{\infty}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{t-w}+1}\mathrm dt$$
$$= \int_0^{w}\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{w-t}+1}\right)t^{p-1}\mathrm dt+  \int_w^{\infty}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{t-w}+1}\mathrm dt\Rightarrow$$
$$ -Li_p(-e^w) = \frac{w^p}{\Gamma(p+1)} \mathbf{-} \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^{w}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{w-t}+1}\mathrm dt + \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_w^{\infty}\frac{t^{p-1}}{e^{t-w}+1}\mathrm dt$$
(note the sign in front of the second term).

Furthermore, their next result reads

$   -Li_p(-e^w) = \frac{w^p}{\Gamma(p+1)} + \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(w+s)^{p-1}-(w-s)^{p-1}}{e^{s}+1}\mathrm ds - \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_w^{\infty}\frac{(w-s)^{p-1}}{e^{s}+1}\mathrm ds, $

yet I obtain

$   -Li_p(-e^w) = \frac{w^p}{\Gamma(p+1)} + \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(w+s)^{p-1}-(w-s)^{p-1}}{e^{s}+1}\mathrm ds + \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_w^{\infty}\frac{(w-s)^{p-1}}{e^{s}+1}\mathrm ds.$

I start with the previous formula I derived and make two changes of variables $s=w-t$ and $s=t-w$ in second and third terms, respectively.

I see only 3 possible explanations for these disrepancies:

1. The translation from LaTeX went so wrong, that the signs $+$ and $-$ went haywire.
2. The author of the text made either calculation or typing mistakes
3. I've made an error somewhere.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Your formula with minus is correct, and the one with two pluses is not. The easiest way to check this is by numerics (e.g. choosing some random values for $p$ and $w$). I think it should be a typing mistake, probably even not due to the author himself.

Comment: @O.L. are you sure about the last part? If I take $w=0$, my version reduces to the integral representation of $-Li_p(-1)$, and Wood's version has an additional term $-\frac{2}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(-s)^{p-1}}{e^s+1}\mathrm ds$

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the last part? I haven't looked at the last two formulas of your post, if that was your question.

Comment: @O.L. Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for checking my calculations!